# How to get the element type of a JQuery object

Tags: jquery, typescript

I am trying to overload a typescript method:

```
private togglePencilButton(x: JQuery<HTMLElement>);
private togglePencilButton(x: JQuery<Event>);
private togglePencilButton(x: JQuery<Event> | JQuery<HTMLElement>) {
}
```

Now I need to differentiate if the parameter is a JQuery<Event> or JQuery<HTMLElement>.

I'm not aware how to get the element type of an object, just the type of it:

```
if (x instanceof JQuery){...}
```

getting the element type of JQuery doesn't work as planned

```
if (x instanceof JQuery<Event>){...} // Cannot use namespace 'JQuery' as a value.ts(2708)
```

I also tried `instanceof JQuery.Event` but also to no avail.

Somebody has a solution?